# How to remove a dom element without any page jump?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to remove an element from the DOM without having the page jump.

I have tried using a phantom element that has the same height. When reaching a certain scroll position, I tried removing my element from the DOM, and setting my phantom element to show. This still causes flicker however.

Sticky spacer has a height of 1000px, and phantom spacer has a height of 0. When they have a class of animation-done, phantom spacer shows with 1000px height and sticky spacer has a height of 0.

```
jQuery('.phantom-container, .sticky-spacer').addClass('animation-done');
```

I would have expected my solution to work, but I still see a flicker. Is there any bull-proof method of doing this?

The method I've used is also located  in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dgk17pq9/13/

Comment: Can we get some code?

Comment: do you mean 100px or 1000px?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I meant 1000px. Edited.

Comment: Why not place the DIV (to be hidden) inside another DIV with fixed height. All you will do then is show/hide the DIV inside. No jumping, no flickers! You can even set the height of outer DIV from the height of inner DIV using JQuery right before hiding (in case the contents are dynamic and you do not know the height).

Comment: Don't remove the div from the DOM at all, you don't have to. The user will never be able to see it.

Comment: @NawedKhan I've tried that. If the user scrolls fast enough, there is still a flicker.

Comment: Please include a [mre] **in the question itself**, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (click the icon with `<>`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact code but I tweaked your fiddle and it appears to have no jump or flicker even if you scroll fast.

[Here is the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/woncxv2s/)

I have moved the sticky div inside the phantom div.
I am setting the height of phantom div once, on page load.
I am only working (adding/removing class) with the sticky div, not the phantom div. The phantom div remains there all the time hence no flicker.

Here is the sample code from fiddle:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#content-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);

  // Set the height of $sticky-phantom
  $('#sticky-phantom').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());

  sticky_relocate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add position:fixed to the element, it gets removed  from its place and sticks it at the top of the page. Rest of your content jumps up because the element bar is not in the same place anymore.

Take a look at the demo I found: 
http://jsfiddle.net/1e1cg6t5/

In order to fix the issue, you need to dynamically change the css classes that manipulate the paddings of particular sections like in the code from the link above:

```
if (scrollPos >= navPos) {
        $navBar.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $navBar.removeClass('fixed');
    }
```

where:

```
.nav-wrapper .nav {
    height: 80px;
    background: #333;
    padding: 0 40px;
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.nav-wrapper .nav.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I hope that helps :)